# OpenNi Callback - Wrong datatype

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, openni

In the sample code we have the following:

```
void
grabberCallback(const PointCloud<PointXYZRGBA>::ConstPtr& cloud)
{

}
```

Unfortunately, the data type I need for processing is a

```
PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud
```

How on earth do I convert it to this form?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help:

http://answers.ros.org/question/9515/how-to-convert-between-different-point-cloud-types-using-pcl/

Note that it might be old (dated around 2011)

Answer (score 0):

You may change the grabber to use:

```
 void grabberCallback(const PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr& cloud) {

 }
```

This callback can be of any Pointcloud type ([here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php) you can read about all the types available). Since you mentioned that it was from the sample, I suggest to change this...

If you want to convert it try using:

```
pcl::copyPointCloud (input, output)
```

as explained by Radu in [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/pcl-PointCloud-lt-pcl-PointXYZRGBA-gt-pcl-PointCloud-lt-pcl-PointXYZRGB-gt-conversion-td4022360.html)....

Also, I will suggest to use always PointXYZRGBA, PointXYRGB is deprecated and in the past it has caused me some weird behaviours....